# Norm of a Taylor approximation of a multivariate function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, taylor-series

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. My goal is to bound the first order Taylor approximation of $f$. Given $x,x'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ I have that
\begin{equation}
f(x)-f(x')\approx (x-x')^TDf(x')+(x-x')^THf(x')(x-x')+\mathcal{O}\left(\left\Vert x-x' \right\Vert^3\right),
\end{equation}
where $Df(x')$ and $Hf(x')$ define the Jacobian and Hessian w.r.t $x'$, respectively. Taking the 2-norm of each side we get

\begin{align}
\left\Vert f(x)-f(x')-(x-x')^TDf(x')\right\Vert_2&\leq \left\Vert(x-x')^THf(x')(x-x')\right\Vert_2\\
&\leq\left\Vert H f(x')\right \Vert_2\left\Vert x-x'\right \Vert^2_2 \quad (\text{operator norm}).\\
&\leq C \left\Vert x-x'\right \Vert^2_2\\
\end{align}

My goal is to bound (and find $C$) such that $\left\Vert Hf(x') \right \Vert_2\leq C$. The confusion I have is that as $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, the Jacobian and Hessian are both tensors. Is the correct approach to split $f=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n)$ and take $n$ separate Taylor approximations of $f_j:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ for $j=1:n$ and then we would have $\left\Vert Hf(x') \right \Vert_2^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\left\Vert Hf_j(x') \right\Vert_2^2$ where $Hf_j(x')$ is the individual Hessian of $f_j$ at the point $x'$ ?

Or am I missing something blindingly obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

Comments
I posted it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130396/finding-the-norm-of-the-taylor-approximation-of-a-multivariate-function-f-math/4133505#4133505) but didn't get the answer I was looking for.

Comment: There are no such bounds in general.  Perhaps you forgot to qualify your question?  Let $f$ be a cubic function $f(x)=x^3$, then $Hf = 6x$, so there is no such bound in this case.